# What is vegur appearing in HTTP headers?

Tags: http, headers

On some websites there are the following headers which consist `vegur`, e.g.

```
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

In [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/404) (check the headers) and also in that [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/641076/pci-failure-due-to-http-reverse-proxy-detection).

I've tried to look for it, but I couldn't find it. Is this is generated by [Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)), some kind of reverse proxy or it's something else?

Comment: @AFH I don't think so. What font has to do with HTTP headers?

Comment: Vegur seems to be some sort of (reverse/caching) proxy that heroku uses. There's no cite for this, gathering from a websearch where I see most places referencing vegur(other than the font) are present in header responses from heroku. Incidentally, both your links point to sites served by Heroku

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a **Heroku** proxy/load-balancer adding the `Via` header.

---

See: [Vegur at GitHub](https://github.com/heroku/vegur).

> Heroku's proxy library based on a forked Cowboy frontend (Cowboyku). This library handles proxying in Heroku's routing stack.

Comment: Looks like Vegur is open source (not sure when they open sourced it, but commits go back to 2013): https://github.com/heroku/vegur

Comment: Open source release announcement https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2015-10-21-vegur-free-software/

Answer (score 8):

The `via` header shows proxies and their names. In this case, the client went through a proxy called "vegur" - either its software or the computer name.